# Create a string by reversion of utf8 php

Tags: php, utf-8

I am looking for some code in PHP that can verify the following test :

```
json_encode(utf8_encode(theFunction(chr(0xEF). chr(0x82) .chr(0x96)))) === '"\uf096";
```

Doesn't the function `theFunction` actually exist ?

Comment: No, doesn't look like "theFunction" is a predefined function in PHP. I'm guessing you copied this code out of some instructions that were vague (purposefully omitting the code for theFunction)? Is this a homework assignment or something?

Comment: What I meant is that I'm looking for some code to write that fits the use Or wrote. I need a way to create a string that is converted into \uf096

Comment: This is not a homework assignment, it is a simplification of a problem I have : sending the json \uf096 from a string that MUST be utf8 encoded...